# Get sAMAccountNames from CSV of Proxy Address powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I have got the value in the file is under the SMTPproxyaddresses header.So, I'm trying something along this lines.

```
foreach ($user in $userID)
{

    $ADuser = Get-ADUser -Filter "ProxyAddress -eq $($user.SMTPproxyaddresses)" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, SAMAccountName
}
```

CSV file :

```
SMTPproxyaddresses
userproxy@contoso.com
testproxy@contoso.com
user2proxy@contoso.com
user3proxy@contoso.com
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Use `Import-Csv` to import the CSV file and then loop though all "SMTPproxyaddresses".
Looks, like you are on the right path, whats the issue?

Comment: I am getting Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'ProxyAddress -eq user@contoso.com' Error Message: 'syntax error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it working with a variable inside the Filter parameter, but it worked typed outright. However, the alternative is using an LDAPFilter and this worked for me.

```
    Get-AdUser -LDAPfilter "(ProxyAddresses=*$($user.SMTPaddresses))" -Properties whenCreated, Enabled, SamAccountName
```

Comment: I am getting Get-ADUser : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the 
"path" argument and run the operation again

Comment: is there any comment?

Comment: I couldn't get a variable working either. I've updated the answer with a solution that worked for me.